# Adding extras to all my products

Tags: product-attribute

I have a restaurant store and  want to add extra options on each product that ihave in my store.

For example, I have product: http://store.hbros.co.uk/guacamole-falafel-salad.html

And I want to add these extras: jalapeños or sundries tomatoes.

But rather than doing this product by product, I wonder if I can make this on all products.

Comment: did not got point `want to add these extras: jalapeños or sundries tomatoes.`

Comment: I want to add both options, so the user can select one of those. I can add them both choices manually, but I want to know if there exists other way to do this.